# jquery how to get this dialog Ok button to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The dialog is displayed and works perfectly. The top right "X" Close button properly dismisses the dialog, but the OK button does nothing.
(I'm using jquery 1.9.1)

```
  function showFollowProjectInDialog(followurl){
      $.ajax({
        url: followurl,
        success: function(data) {
          $("#TFdialog").html(data).dialog({
            resizable: true,
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal:true,
            buttons: {
            Ok: function() {$( "#TFdialog" ).dialog( "close" );}
            },
            }).dialog('open');
        }
      });
    }
```

I've also tried it without the comma following the button like:

```
buttons: {
    Ok: function() {$( "#TFdialog" ).dialog( "close" );}
        }
}).dialog('open');
```

And I've tried these:

```
buttons: [{
            text: "Ok",
            Click : function () {
                $("#TFdialog").dialog("close");
            }
        }]
```

and:

```
buttons: [{
 Ok: function() {
     $("#TFdialog").dialog("close");
 }
}]
```

and I've tried replacing the "#TFdialog" with 'this' like:

```
$(this).dialog("close");
```

Comment: Have you tried with buttons: { "Ok": <your_code> } ?

Comment: Which of the 4 million jquery plugins for `dialog` are you using?

Comment: Using jquery like this:
<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing

```
    buttons: [
    {
        text: "Ok",
        click: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
          // your code goes here
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Isn't this missing a closing bracket like : ]  ?

Comment: Got it!
This works:

buttons: [
      {
          text: "Ok",
          click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( 'close' );
          }
        }
  ]

No final comma and the closing bracket did the trick.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assumption is you use jQuery UI Reference https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form

```
buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
```

You can also use the dialog as an object:

```
var myDialog;
myDialog = $("#TFdialog").html(data).dialog({
            resizable: true,
            autoOpen: false,// added this
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal:true,
            buttons: {
               Ok: function() {
                  myDialog.dialog( "close" );
                  },
              "Close this Soon" : DelayClose,
            }
            });
myDialog.dialog('open');

function DelayClose(){
   setTimeout(function() {
    myDialog.dialog( "close" );
  }, 500 );
}
```

Example for why to use an object for yours:

```
var myDialog;
myDialog = $("#TFdialog").dialog({
            resizable: true,
            autoOpen: false,// added this
            height: 600,
            width: 700,
            modal:true,
            buttons: {
               Ok: function() {
                  myDialog.dialog( "close" );
                  }
            }
            });

function showFollowProjectInDialog(followurl){
    $.ajax({
        url: followurl
    }).done(function(data){
        $("#TFdialog").html(data);
        myDialog.dialog('open');
    });
}
```

Comment: This example does not produce a dialog, this just displays the ajax result inline with no modal box, no close button, etc.

Comment: I have not insight into your ajax data but with the assumption it IS html it seems to work:  https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/jr5adf7a/  Note you DO have to wrap this in document ready most likely